# Pyspark fill() not replacing the NULL values

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to change the NULL value into a string "Missing Value".

Here is how the data is present in test2.csv file.

```
+----+----+----------+------+
|Name| Age|Experience|Salary|
+----+----+----------+------+
|him1|  31|        10| 40000|
|him2|  30|         8| 35000|
|him3|  29|         4| 30000|
|him4|  28|         3| 25000|
|him5|  27|         2| 20000|
|him6|  26|         1| 15000|
|him7|    |          | 40000|
|    |  35|        10| 35000|
|    |  36|          |      |
+----+----+----------+------+
```

putting the value in df_pyspark variable-:

```
df_pyspark=spark.read.csv(file_path,header=True,inferSchema=True)

result-: DataFrame[Name: string, Age: int, Experience: int, Salary: int]

+----+----+----------+------+
|Name| Age|Experience|Salary|
+----+----+----------+------+
|him1|  31|        10| 40000|
|him2|  30|         8| 35000|
|him3|  29|         4| 30000|
|him4|  28|         3| 25000|
|him5|  27|         2| 20000|
|him6|  29|         1| 15000|
|him7|NULL|      NULL| 10000|
|NULL|  23|         2| 23233|
|NULL|  34|      NULL|  NULL|
+----+----+----------+------+
```

## 1.

```
df_pyspark.na.fill(value='Missing Values').show() 

+--------------+----+----------+------+
|          Name| Age|Experience|Salary|
+--------------+----+----------+------+
|          him1|  31|        10| 40000|
|          him2|  30|         8| 35000|
|          him3|  29|         4| 30000|
|          him4|  28|         3| 25000|
|          him5|  27|         2| 20000|
|          him6|  26|         1| 15000|
|          him7|NULL|      NULL| 40000|
|Missing Values|  35|        10| 35000|
|Missing Values|  36|      NULL|  NULL|
+--------------+----+----------+------+
```

Only in Name column the values are changing.

## 2.

```
df_pyspark.na.fill(value=0).show()

+----+---+----------+------+
|Name|Age|Experience|Salary|
+----+---+----------+------+
|him1| 31|        10| 40000|
|him2| 30|         8| 35000|
|him3| 29|         4| 30000|
|him4| 28|         3| 25000|
|him5| 27|         2| 20000|
|him6| 29|         1| 15000|
|him7|  0|         0| 10000|
|NULL| 23|         2| 23233|
|NULL| 34|         0|     0|
+----+---+----------+------+
```

Only in Age, Experience and Salary column the values are changing.

Can someone tell me why this is happening? I need to change all the NULL values to string 'Missing Values'.

Comment: One observation to make is the first column is string datatype, while the other 3 columns are number datatype.

Comment: you can't fill an integer column with string values. hence, passing a string does nothing to the int columns.